# Update only permitted columns in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Can I use hibernate to permit user to change some columns based on some conditions? There is (updatable = false) in column annotation, can I change it dynamically or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special support for this in Hibernate. A column should be `updatable='true'`, if there is ever any case that can update the column. You should do this in your service layer or hide the related field from the UI or similar.